# Navigation Drop-Down Toggle Issues with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I recently had my Wordpress site's homepage redesigned at www.seosherpas.com.

That was designed on a theme that uses Bootstrap. It is implemented on Thesis by taking the code of the customized site, which is installed in a sub-folder, and copied and pasted into a custom page template.

Now I'm trying to mimic the navigation menu site-wide on my customized Thesis design: www.seosherpas.com/blog/

I've managed to mimic the design, but cannot get the drop down menus to work. I have a feeling it's an issue with how I'm calling Bootstrap's Javascript... maybe, maybe not. I really have no idea.

I have this line of code to temporarily hide the dropdown:

```
.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu {
border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
/* Temporary Fix??? display: block; */
}
```

If I show 'display: block;' the drop down appears but is always appearing, instead of only when hovering.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.nav-collapse:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

And you'll only see the dropdown when you hover over the .nav-collapse element which is the dropdown's parent.  Works every time, every browser. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, Josh! That almost completely does the trick. Now when I hover over one list, all three open up. Thoughts?

Comment: Never mind! Got it:

    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu{
    display: block;    
    }

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Hmm... actually, not working entirely. Now the top link in the drop down list doesn't work... :(

Comment: If you have a jsFiddle for this, I'd be happy to fix it up for you.

Comment: Hi Josh,

Got it figured out :-) There was a class I had to remove on the links. Working great now!

Thank you for your help!